Running redshift configuration settings within Excel's VBA?
In VBA I want to run enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true just before the actual select statement. In sqlworkbench the script works as expected. This is running against an Amazon redshift database.
Unfortunately, the same sql snippet doesn't work in VBA. No error is given - it just doesn't run the select statement.
Is there any other way to run this in VBA? Or maybe I'm running it wrong?
This is the code:
Sub Find_Data()
 
Dim sql As String

sql = "SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true; " & _
    "select " & _
    "empl_name as " & Chr(34) & "Employee Name" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
    "empl_city as " & Chr(34) & "Employee City" & Chr(34) & ", " & _
    "EmpId " & _
    "from  " & _
    "Redshift.EmployeeTable"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  
Sheets("Data").Select
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("redshiftdb").ODBCConnection
    .CommandText = sql
End With

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


Try splitting up 'set' and the 'select' as separate variables and execute them in that order.
